# cannot load such file -- rack/handler/puma

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rackup, puma

### My setup and the error

I get an error when I start my Sinatra application with rackup and puma. My `config.ru` file looks like this:

```
#\ -s puma
require './controller/main.rb'
run Sinatra::Application
```

So when I now use rackup I get this error:

> /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:76:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/puma (LoadError)

I use ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [i686-linux]

### What I have tried so far

My first thought was that I forgot to install puma, or puma is broken in some way. So I tried:

```
puma -v
puma version 2.0.1
```

And I start it directly with ruby:

```
ruby controller/main.rb 
Puma 2.0.1 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:4567
```

And I found this puma [issue](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/71) but I didn't find a real solution.

### Finally my questions

1. Why id this happening?
2. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using Bundler?

Comment: yes Bundler version 1.3.4

Comment: There's two things I'd try first. 1) I'd sandbox the gems so they don't get mixed up with those installed by Rubygems. Remove current bundler stuff with `rm -rf .bundle Gemfile.lock bin vendor` and run `bundle install --binstubs --path vendor`. Now all the exes are in the local bin dir and all the gems in the local vendor dir. 2) Run using `bundle exec`, but since the `binstubs` command was used you can instead run `bin/rackup config.ru`. See if that improves things / brings back a different error.

Comment: okay this work can you explain why? and can you add it as answer so I can accept it. And funny is now I can also use the global rackup

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Sandbox the gems so they don't get mixed up with those installed by Rubygems.

   Remove current bundler stuff with

   ```
   rm -rf .bundle Gemfile.lock bin vendor
   ```

   and then run

   ```
   bundle install --binstubs --path vendor
   ```

   This installs all gems into `vendor/RUBY-ENGINE/VERSION/` and all executables into the `bin` dir. These are separate from the ones installed via the `gem` command, which will be system wide.
2. Run using `bundle exec`, but since the `--binstubs` command was used you can instead run

   ```
   bin/rackup config.ru
   ```

By using `bundle exec` or one of the executables from `bin/` you're telling Bundler to only use the gems that ***it*** installed. If you installed Puma with Bundler then it will install the Puma handler with the Rack that Bundler installed. But, you'll probably have another version of Rack installed by Rubygems (via `gem install rack -r`) that *doesn't* have the handler. To get the right one, sandbox your project's gems and always run stuff from the `bin/` directory. If you need the `ruby` command then use `bundle exec ruby…` and Bundler will load the correct gems for the project.

I do this with every project now and only install gems via `gem install…` if I need them system wide. It also makes sure you don't miss any gems out of the Gemfile because you had them already available on your system - no nasty surprises on deployment!

Answer (score 4):

Try to be sure you have

```
require "rack/handler/puma"
```

This is one that

```
Rack::Handler::Puma.run
```

needs.

Play with this http://gabebw.com/blog/2015/08/10/advanced-rack