# RSpec.configure not working and examples fails due to rspec-mocks#setup

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, rspec-mocks

I'am started rspec 3 months ago and i'am working with it in a sinatra project (using ruby 2.1.1) ...

I don't have errors in my specs (they're successfully running in other computers) but while running them on my own i got this for every single example ...

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-mocks-2.14.6/lib/rspec/mocks.rb:10:in `setup'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/mocking_adapters/rspec.rb:17:in `setup_mocks_for_rspec'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:337:in `run_before_example'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:147:in `block in run'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:299:in `with_around_example_hooks'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:145:in `run'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:494:in `block in run_examples'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:490:in `map'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:490:in `run_examples'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:457:in `run'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `block in run'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `map'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:458:in `run'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `map'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block in run_specs'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:54:in `report'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108:in `run_specs'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
 # /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
 # 
 #   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
 #   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
 #   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.
```

==========================

I used this link (https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/754) but it's not working for me (my app is in a folder named projects) ...

I've also tried to use ruby 2.0.0 but it's the same issue ...

I'll be happy to read any helpful writing about it ... thanks

Comment: Sounds like some mess with your gems, try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16656270/1279355 and try it again

Comment: Works for me ... Thanks!!! but i really don't undestand why it refused to work

Comment: I hope my answer help you a bit to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is your ruby load a version of rspec or rspec-mock which is not corresponding with your code.

So to fix this sandbox your gems.

```
#clean up
$ rm -rf .bundle Gemfile.lock bin vendor

#install
$ bundle install --binstubs --path vendor

#run
$ bundle exec ruby yourfile.rb
$ bin/rackup
```

With this you made sure that your project use the specified gems from the gemfiles and not any gem which can surprisingly be installed on your system. This can also prevent crazy load path errors. So I would recommend to use this for every project.

Comment: Other users might only need to install specific rspec version to match the version they need: ig.

 `sudo gem install rspec -v 2.99`