# Rails server doesn't start in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, production-environment

I'm trying to start my first production rails server on `DigitalOcean` but after

```
$ rails server — binding=my_Droplet_ip_address
```

i get this error

```
Exiting
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:78:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/— (LoadError)
from /home/glaux/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:78:in `try_require'
    from /home/glaux/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:16:in `get'
    from /home/glaux/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:290:in `server'
```

And so on.

App works fine locally and simple `rails s` on server also works fine.

I have `Ubuntu 14.04` server with `postgres`, `nginx` and `passenger`.

I'm a complete newbie to it and I may have missed something important. So tell me if you want me to provide any other info on this matter.

Comment: Have you had a look at this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647089/cannot-load-such-file-rack-handler-puma

Comment: I think its ruby version issue, make sure the ruby you are using is `v 2.3.0`

Comment: and its `rails s --binding=IP` not `rails s -- binding=IP`

Comment: @XtraSimplicity yes, i stumbled upon it but it's a bit different matter i guess and i didn't understand how can i use it to solve my problem

Comment: @SeyboGlaux, my theory was that it may've been an issue with the gems (and thus re-installing them might get you somewhere). Good to see that it wasn't the issue, however. :)

Comment: @illusionist thanks! The space was a problem. I have copied this line from a tutorial and this mistake was there. Should have noticed it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`
And **stop previous port 3000** used by rails

To stop previous port. Try this command 
`Lsof wni -p 3000`

If you are running on `3000` port